# Typescript: specified object with fromJson method, how to test if private property exists and than set it

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

i have a object that contains a fromJson method. this method is not working because private property of the class can not be accessed? what is wrong and how to handle it? Code is written in TypeScript.

```
class Example {
    private Foo: string; // does not matter if private or public, same effect, and normaly has to be private

    constructor(input?: string) {
        if (!!input) {
            this.foo = input;    
        }
    }

    set foo(value: string) {
        this.Foo = value;
    }
    get foo(): string {
        return this.Foo;
    }

    public static fromJson(obj: Object) {
        let result: Example = new Example();
        for (let index in obj) {
            if (Example.hasOwnProperty(index)) { // never runs because false
                result[index] = obj[index];
            }

            /* allready tried this -> same result */
            // if (result.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
            //    result[index] = obj[index];
            //}

            // let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Example, index); // = undefined
            // let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(result, index); // = undefined
        }
        return result;
    }

    public toJsonString() {
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    }

    public toJsonObject() {
        return JSON.parse(this.toJsonString());
    }
}

let a = new Example('one');
let json = a.toJsonObject();  // this looks exactly like my api response (type json)
let obj = Example.fromJson(json);
console.log(json);
console.log(obj);
```

but the `console.log(obj)` has to be `<Example> {"Foo": "one", foo(...)}`

EDIT: generated JavaScript:

```
var Example = (function () {
    function Example(input) {
        if (!!input) {
            this.foo = input;
        }
    }
    Object.defineProperty(Example.prototype, "foo", {
        get: function () {
            return this.Foo;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            this.Foo = value;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    Example.fromJson = function (obj) {
        var result = new Example();
        for (var index in obj) {
            if (Example.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
                result[index] = obj[index];
            }
        }
        return result;
    };
    Example.prototype.toJsonString = function () {
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    };
    Example.prototype.toJsonObject = function () {
        return JSON.parse(this.toJsonString());
    };
    return Example;
}());
var a = new Example('one');
var json = a.toJsonObject(); // this looks exactly like my api response (type json)
var obj = Example.fromJson(json);
console.log(json);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: What does the generated javascript look like?

Comment: @Arg0n put it to question via edit

Comment: What happens with the generated JS if you assign a value to `Foo`? `private Foo: string = null;`

Comment: ArgOn is right. Every property has to be initialized to access via hasOwnProperty function. i post a working sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Example {
    private Foo: string = undefined;
    private Foo2: number = undefined;

    constructor(input?: string) {
        if (!!input) {
            this.foo = input;    
        }
    }

    set foo(value: string) {
        this.Foo = value;
    }
    get foo(): string {
        return this.Foo;
    }

    set numeric(value: number) {
        this.Foo2 = value;
    }
    get numeric(): number {
        return this.Foo2;
    }

    public static fromJson(obj: Object) {
        let result: Example = new Example();
        for (let index in obj) {
            if (result.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
                result[index] = obj[index]; // care, has to be result
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public toJsonString() {
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    }

    public toJsonObject() {
        return JSON.parse(this.toJsonString());
    }
}

let a = new Example('one');
let json = a.toJsonObject();
let obj = Example.fromJson(json);
console.log(json);
console.log(obj);
```

i think this is the solution you are looking for. positive effect, if you initialize your properties with undefined, your toJson methods don't list the arguments. so your request traffic is not so big.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. now it's a stupid handwork to initialize all properties in all my models ;)