# How do I pipe/map to return an array in Angular 7

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe, angular7, rxjs6

When I make a GET call via HttpClient I want to pass back an array of the actual typed objects, vs. just a generic 'object', and so I tried to do this:

```js
getExistingArsByLab(labId: number): Observable<EhsAssessmentAr[]> {
    return this.http
        .get<EhsAssessmentAr[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/ar?labId=${labId}`)
        .pipe(
            map(x => {
                const ret = EhsAssessmentAr.fromJson(x);
                ret.ar = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, ret.ar.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'));
                return ret;
            })
        )
}
```

That `fromJson` method is declared to return the proper class, and I thought since I was sending this through `map` that I'd get back an array.  I'm REALLY new to RxJs so I'm sure I'm just doing something completely stupid there.

I'm getting theerror:

> TS2322: Type 'Observable<EhsAssessmentAr>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<EhsAssessmentAr[]>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Observable<{}> not assignable to type Observable<SomeType\[\]>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221062/observable-not-assignable-to-type-observablesometype)

Comment: Doesn’t seem the same to me. I declared as an array return type and I feel like I am returning an array type. What you pointed at was returning array or object.

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/43233448/4591364 ?

Comment: were you be able to fix the problem?

Comment: Not at my computer but I think the issue is the map I used takes the array not a single object like the “normal” map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **strong type your mapping** response and Check you are returning **array** not single element:

```js
getExistingArsByLab(labId: number): Observable<EhsAssessmentAr[]> {
    return this.http
        .get<EhsAssessmentAr[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/ar?labId=${labId}`)
        .pipe(
            map((x:EhsAssessmentAr[]) => {
                const ret = EhsAssessmentAr.fromJson(x);
                ret.ar = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, ret.ar.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'));
                return ret;
            })
        )
}
```

**Pro-tip 2:** If you are changing return type for any reason you can use:

```
return <TypedArray[]> arrParsed["something"];
```

**Pro-tip 3:** Angular hates you feed it with html so you need to find some cool solution like when templating adding a replace of token to new line

Comment: Yes, that's better and compatible with RxJS V6.0++, thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is already the default behavior of Angular 7 HttpClient.  So unless you need to do some extra processing of html or something like in your example, you just need the following:

```
getExistingArsByLab(labId: number): Observable<EhsAssessmentAr[]> {
  return this.http
    .get<EhsAssessmentAr[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/ar?labId=${labId}`)
}
```